# How to version a project with dependencies and data sources

Tags: versioning, semantic-versioning

My apologies if my question is not gonna be clear as I do not have experience in the domain of versioning products/projects. And starting: I have a project which has multiple libraries and data sources dependencies and each library depends to another library or data source. For example:

```
   <-- L1 <-- L2 <-- DS1
P1                    |
   <--------- L3 <----|
```

Where `P1` is the project, `L1-3` is libraries and `DS1` is a data source. `DS1` has no functionallity, just adding or removing data from it. The final output of the project `P1` is a data table. In a point of view the project is not a software but data.

What I want is to use a 'versioning system' which incorporates the changes in each library or data source.

And here are my thoughts.Initially I thought of the following:

- `P1` will have an `alpha`,'beta` etc versioning ( which is always dependand of the versions of libraries and data sources).
- libraries will have a semantic like versioning and
- data sources just an incremental number(etc 1,2,3 etc)

And this would be released internally as:

```
 --------------------------------------
|project Ver|  L1  |  L2  |  L3  | DS1 |
|--------------------------------------|
|   A       |  1.0 |  1.1 |  1.3 | 1   |
|   B       |  1.2 |  1.2 |  1.4 | 1   |
|   C       |  1.4 |  1.3 |  1.5 | 1   |
|   D       |  1.5 |  1.5 |  2.8 | 2   |
                   .
                   .
                   .
```

But As i mentioned before some libraries are dependent to some other libraries or data sources and these information are not in that table. How can incorporate it?

If a data source change version (change of the data) should the dependand version change or remain the same?

Gennerally, how would you aproach this problem? Any insights are useful.

Answer (score 4):

Since the real objective of the project is the *output data table*, I'm inclined to add yet another version number for the output itself.  Let's call that `OUTPUT`.

So now we have all of these things being versioned:

```
+--------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-----+
| OUTPUT |  P1   |  L1   |  L2   |  L3   | DS1 |
+--------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-----+
```

Where

- `OUTPUT` is the data table output
- `P1` is the main program
- `L1` - `L3` are libraries
- `DS1` is the data source

Semantic versioning should be a big help.  You can "bubble up" compatibility changes ("major" version changes in semantic terminology) where either the output or the dependencies may be affected.

As you've already concluded, semantic versioning is pointless for the data source (`DT1`), since *all* changes are "compatibility changes" in terms of the output.

Here's how your (surprisingly fast) project history might go:

```
+-----+--------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-----+
|     | OUTPUT |  P1   |  L1   |  L2   |  L3   | DS1 |
+-----+--------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-----+
| Sun |      1 | 1.0.0 | 1.0.0 | 1.0.0 | 1.0.0 |   1 |
| Mon |      1 | 1.0.1 | 1.0.0 | 1.0.0 | 1.0.0 |   1 |
| Tue |      1 | 1.0.1 | 1.3.0 | 1.0.0 | 1.0.0 |   1 |
| Wed |      1 | 1.1.0 | 2.0.0 | 1.0.0 | 1.0.0 |   1 |
| Thu |      2 | 1.1.0 | 2.0.0 | 1.0.0 | 1.0.0 |   2 |
| Fri |      3 | 2.0.0 | 2.0.0 | 1.0.0 | 1.0.0 |   2 |
| Sat |      3 | 2.0.0 | 2.0.0 | 1.1.0 | 2.0.0 |   2 |
+-----+--------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-----+
```

- On Sunday, you've started the project and all versions are at 1 or 1.0.0.
- On Monday, the main project `P1` gets a bug fix and the version is updated to `1.0.1`. No other version changes are needed. You've programmatically confirmed that this  bug fix has not affected `OUTPUT`.
- On Tuesday, library `L1` gets a minor change. It is not a compatibility change, so the version of `P1` and `OUTPUT` will not need changing.
- On Wednesday, library `L1` gets a major change.  Because of this, your main project `P1` needs to be changed as well.  However, you've programmatically confirmed that `OUTPUT` has not been affected, so its version does not change.
- On Thursday, the data source `DS1` has been updated. Now the version of `OUTPUT` will change as well.
- On Friday, the main application `P1` has had a major change, which also affects `OUTPUT`.
- On Saturday, library `L1` gets a major change. Library `L2` depends on library `L1`, so it gets a minor change. Nothing else is affected by this change.

I believe that to do this properly will require great discipline.  I would recommend maintaining a table much like this one (with actual dates replacing the days of the week, of course) along with very clear notes about dependencies - especially inter-library dependencies!

Every change should be examined carefully for side-effects which "bubble up" through the dependency graph.  Having a table should greatly help with this.

Any compatibility change that affects a dependency *must* update the major version number for this scheme to have a hope of working. A library might get up to version 102.0.0.  That's okay, there are plenty of numbers. :-)